# What panel to use

Tags: wpf, layout

I have a collection of objects (same type) that I like to display in my view (WPF).
These objects are some kind of print previews, so every object is a page that could be printed in portrait mode (height is bigger than width).

At first I used a WPF `TabControl` to put every preview page in a separate tab. That worked fine, every page was displayed as big a possible inside the tab. But I couldn't get the visuals of all objects out of the `TabControl` at print time, because of the construction of the `TabControl` (it only holds the visual of the currently selected tab).

So I thought about putting them inside a horizontal `StackPanel`. But I can't figure out how to make the objects inside the `StackPanel` be as big as possible. It seems that the `StackPanel` shows my preview pages as small as possible, I'd like them to be as big as possible.

I tried to set the `HorizontalAlignment` and the `VerticalAlignment` of the control in the `ItemTemplate` to `Stretch`, but that didn't help.
I tried to bind the `Height` of the control in the `ItemTemplate` to the `ActualHeight` of the `ItemsControl`, but that didn't help either (I can't even explain what it did with this binding in place).

I googled but the best I could come up with was writing my own `Panel`.

Is this really the way to go or is there some way to persuade the `StackPanel` to make it's children as big as possible (at least in the dimension it's not stacking in).

Comment: Hello, could a viewbox help in your case?

Comment: As described. I would probably bind a collection of viewmodels to the itemssource of the tabcontrol. Template those out into the item you see. If you need to print all of them then template each in turn out into a container in memory. Force measure and arrange on that and then rendertargetbitmap or however you want to generate a picture to print. And do that for each in the collection.

Comment: @DarkTemplar: `ViewBox` is a bad idea almost every time, since it inflates everything (even the `BorderSize` or the `StrokeThickness`), and there's no `SizeScope`, so you can't do something like "Inflate every object in the collection so that **the biggest one** fills all the space (but the smaller ones got the same scale factor").

Comment: @Andy: I already tried something like that (`For Each` through the tabs in code, get the `Visual` of the `SelectedItem` and print it), but I couldn't get it to work the way I want it. Maybe I have to try harder. Thank you.